# How to set a setting to move cursor to next line after writing 250 alphabets in a line?

Tags: editors, winedt

I am getting some problem in Tex writing. Can any one tell me how to set a setting to move cursor (automatically) to next line after writing 250 alphabets in a line? I am using ***WinEdt.***

P.S. I want my cursor to move to new line while am typing my text in a .tex file. Somewhat like only 250 characters in a row.

Comment: It is not clear. Do you want to put exactly 250 characters in the produced output? Or do you mean something else?

Comment: Do you mean 250 characters? Are you talking about the code itself in the `.tex` file? Then the answer would depend on the editor you're using, but you haven't said which one that is.

Comment: that's depending on the editor you're using.

Comment: Edited the question. I am using WinEdt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In WinEdt, `Options` -> `Preferences` -> `Wrapping`, set `Fixed Right Margin` to `250` and check the option `Use fixed Right Margin` as in the picture below

[image]

Probably, however, 250 is a too high value...